# Program fails to count the beverages and total number of persons

Tags: c#

I'm beginner of c sharp language. I need help to compile this program it does not count the beverages and total number of persons

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace survey
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int choice = 0 , coffee = 0, tea = 0, coke = 0, juice = 0, person = 0;
            while (choice != -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n SURVEY ON BEVERAGES ");
                Console.WriteLine("======================== ");
                Console.WriteLine("\n1. COFFEE\n2. TEA\n3. COKE\n4. ORANGE JUICE\n5. PLEASE ENTER -1 TO EXIT\n ");
                Console.Write(" CHOOSE YOUR FAVORITE BEVERAGES FROM THE LIST : ");
                choice = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    coffee++;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    tea++;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    coke++;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    juice++;
                    break;       
            }
            person++; 
            if (choice == -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n\nThe total number of people surveyed is {0}",person);
                Console.WriteLine(" The results are as follows:\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Beverage of choice and votes.\n");

                Console.WriteLine("Coffee = {0}",coffee);
                Console.WriteLine("Tea = {0}",tea);
                Console.WriteLine("Coke = {0}",coke);
                Console.WriteLine("Orange juice = {0}",juice);
            }

        }

    }
    
}
```

Comment: Your `while` loop ends too soon.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. What is the expected result? Where is your code failing? We appreciate you posting code; still, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example -- emphasis on **minimal**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate the different beverand choices, count them and then exit the loop printing the result. Try this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace survey
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int choice = 0 , coffee = 0, tea = 0, coke = 0, juice = 0, person = 0;
            while (choice != -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n SURVEY ON BEVERAGES ");
                Console.WriteLine("======================== ");
                Console.WriteLine("\n1. COFFEE\n2. TEA\n3. COKE\n4. ORANGE JUICE\n5. PLEASE ENTER -1 TO EXIT\n ");
                Console.Write(" CHOOSE YOUR FAVORITE BEVERAGES FROM THE LIST : ");
                choice = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            
            
                switch (choice)
                {
                    case 1:
                        coffee++;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        tea++;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        coke++;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        juice++;
                        break;       
                }
                person++; 
            }
            
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nThe total number of people surveyed is {0}",person);
            Console.WriteLine(" The results are as follows:\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Beverage of choice and votes.\n");

            Console.WriteLine("Coffee = {0}",coffee);
            Console.WriteLine("Tea = {0}",tea);
            Console.WriteLine("Coke = {0}",coke);
            Console.WriteLine("Orange juice = {0}",juice);

        }

    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is that you have a while loop that continues until the choice value is -1. Then when it is -1, you run the switch statement on choice which is -1. The way you can fix this is by putting the switch statement inside your while loop

Answer (score 0):

As you write Case outside of the while loop, this problem raised. You can solve the problem by including Case inside While loop. Here is my code after the modification. You can try this one.

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;


        namespace survey
        {
            class Program
            {
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    int choice = 0, coffee = 0, tea = 0, coke = 0, juice = 0, person = 0;
                    while (choice != -1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n SURVEY ON BEVERAGES ");
                        Console.WriteLine("======================== ");
                        Console.WriteLine("\n1. COFFEE\n2. TEA\n3. COKE\n4. ORANGE JUICE\n5. PLEASE ENTER -1 TO EXIT\n ");
                        Console.Write(" CHOOSE YOUR FAVORITE BEVERAGES FROM THE LIST : ");
                        choice = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

                        switch (choice)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                coffee++;
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                tea++;
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                coke++;
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                juice++;
                                break;
                        }
                        person++;
                    }

                    if (choice == -1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\nThe total number of people surveyed is {0}", person);
                        Console.WriteLine(" The results are as follows:\n");
                        Console.WriteLine("Beverage of choice and votes.\n");

                        Console.WriteLine("Coffee = {0}", coffee);
                        Console.WriteLine("Tea = {0}", tea);
                        Console.WriteLine("Coke = {0}", coke);
                        Console.WriteLine("Orange juice = {0}", juice);
                    }

                }

            }

        }
```